# Sum elements of an array with specific attribute

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I wanna sum the elements of an array, but not all. Let's say that my array is:

```
var example = [
                   {"id": 1, "value": 50, "active": true}, 
                   {"id": 2, "value": 70, "active": false}, 
                   {"id": 3, "value": 45, "active": true}, 
                   {"id": 4, "value": 50, "active": false}
               ];
```

What I need to do is sum just the `values` of the elements with `"active":true`.

There's a way to do that? Maybe is too simple, but right now, my brain is dead.

I'm using Javascript and AngularJs.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like so:

```js
var a = [{"id": 1, "value": 50, "active": true}, {"id": 2, "value": 70, "active": false}, {"id": 3, "value": 45, "active": true}, {"id": 4, "value": 50, "active": false}]

var result = a.filter(o => o.active).reduce((acc, cur) => cur.value + acc, 0)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: @ChuckVillavicencio glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You can prefer a simple syntax...

```
var example = [{"id": 1, "value": 50, "active": true}, {"id": 2, "value": 70, "active": false}, {"id": 3, "value": 45, "active": true}, {"id": 4, "value": 50, "active": false}];
var sum = 0

example.forEach(function(item, index){
  if (item["active"] == true) sum += item["value"];
});

console.log(sum);
```

Comment: Good! Neve thought to use forEach

Answer (score 1):

You can just use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), using the fact that in a numeric context `true = 1` and `false = 0`:

```js
var a = [{"id": 1, "value": 50, "active": true}, {"id": 2, "value": 70, "active": false}, {"id": 3, "value": 45, "active": true}, {"id": 4, "value": 50, "active": false}]

var result = a.reduce((a, c) => a + c.value * c.active, 0)

console.log(result)
```

Or if you prefer, using the ternary operator:

```js
var a = [{"id": 1, "value": 50, "active": true}, {"id": 2, "value": 70, "active": false}, {"id": 3, "value": 45, "active": true}, {"id": 4, "value": 50, "active": false}]

var result = a.reduce((a, c) => a + (c.active ? c.value : 0), 0)

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Cool the fact of numeric value... didn't think about it

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15)
If you need operation on array or collection

import lodash in file where you want to use it

```
import _ from 'lodash';
// or
const _ = require('lodash');
```

Apply [filter](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) and [sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#sumBy)

```
var example = [
 {"id": 1, "value": 50, "active": true}, 
 {"id": 2, "value": 70, "active": false},
 {"id": 3, "value": 45, "active": true}, 
 {"id": 4, "value": 50, "active": false}
];
//Filter all active value
const filterData = _.filter(example, "active");
// const filterData = [
//  {"id": 1, "value": 50, "active": true}, 
//  {"id": 3, "value": 45, "active": true}, 
// ];

//Sum all value filter data
const sum = _.sumBy(filterData, "value");

console.log(sum)
```